# How to delete leases from dhcpd.conf?

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk

I would like to delete leases from `dhcpd.conf` where I give the ip address to be deleted from a Bash variable. A `dhcpd.conf` example is at the button.

However I can't even get it to print a lease I want to delete

```
ip="192.168.234.5"; perl -0777snle 'print if /lease $ip \{.*?\}/' -- -ip=$ip dhcpd.leases
```

Using Perl 5.16.3

**Question**

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
lease 192.168.234.5 {
  starts 3 2018/11/21 18:53:11;
  ends 3 2018/11/21 18:54:11;
  tstp 3 2018/11/21 18:54:11;
  cltt 3 2018/11/21 18:53:11;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 14:99:e2:04:52:5c;
  uid "\001\024\231\342\004R\\";
}
lease 192.168.234.2 {
  starts 3 2018/11/21 20:42:48;
  ends 3 2018/11/21 20:52:48;
  tstp 3 2018/11/21 20:52:48;
  cltt 3 2018/11/21 20:42:48;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:21:5e:90:13:fb;
  set MacAddress = "00:21:5E:90:13:FB";
  set output = "192.168.234.2,00:21:5E:90:13:FB,(host-decl-name n/a),5E9013FB,(dhcp-client-identifier n/a),(vendor-class-identifier n/a),(agent.remote n/a),(agent.circuit n/a)";
}
lease 192.168.234.13 {
  starts 3 2018/11/21 21:38:16;
  ends 3 2018/11/21 21:38:27;
  tstp 3 2018/11/21 21:38:27;
  cltt 3 2018/11/21 21:38:16;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:e0:6f:11:7f:59;
  uid "\001\000\340o\021\177Y";
}
```

Comment: This might be interesting for you: The dhcp server supports a management protocol call [omapi](https://linux.die.net/man/3/omapi). If enabled, you can manage certain types of objects (like leases) while the dhcp server is running. There is a command line client called [omshell](https://linux.die.net/man/1/omshell) which can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @Kubator's [awk answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53445040/900078):

```
# perl -lnse '$f = 0 if /^lease/; $f = 1 if /^lease $ip [{]/; print if not $f;' \
       -- -ip=192.168.234.2 leases
lease 192.168.234.5 {
  starts 3 2018/11/21 18:53:11;
  ends 3 2018/11/21 18:54:11;
  tstp 3 2018/11/21 18:54:11;
  cltt 3 2018/11/21 18:53:11;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 14:99:e2:04:52:5c;
  uid "\001\024\231\342\004R\\";
}
lease 192.168.234.13 {
  starts 3 2018/11/21 21:38:16;
  ends 3 2018/11/21 21:38:27;
  tstp 3 2018/11/21 21:38:27;
  cltt 3 2018/11/21 21:38:16;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:e0:6f:11:7f:59;
  uid "\001\000\340o\021\177Y";
}
```

Comment: Or, perhaps, a bit shorted, `print if /^lease (?!$ip )/ .. /\}/`

Comment: @Dada - im not a heavy perl user and never know it has a `..` operator. cool!

Comment: @Dada What does `(?!$ip )` mean?

Comment: see [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) doc: `(?!pattern)` - A zero-width negative lookahead assertion. For example `/foo(?!bar)/` matches any occurrence of `foo` that isn't followed by `bar`.

Answer (score 3):

> Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Two things.

Firstly, you're reading in the whole file in one go (with `-0777`), which means you lose the ability to easily print a single stanza from your file. Better to use `-0175` which is octal for "}". That way, your code is executed once for each stanza in the input file.

But it still doesn't work. That's because of your regex - `/lease $ip \{.*?\}/`. That dot, by default, matches any character *except a newline*. And as your '{' and '}' characters are always on different lines, that is never going to match.

You could add `/s` to the end of the match operator to change the meaning of `.` to match a newline as well. But I think it's easier to just truncate the regex to only match what's important to you - `/lease $ip \{/`. Actually, I'd add a `^` to the start, just to be really sure.

So, finally, we end up with this:

```
$ ip="192.168.234.5"; perl -0175snle 'print if /^lease $ip \{/' -- -ip=$ip dhcpd.leases
lease 192.168.234.5 {
  starts 3 2018/11/21 18:53:11;
  ends 3 2018/11/21 18:54:11;
  tstp 3 2018/11/21 18:54:11;
  cltt 3 2018/11/21 18:53:11;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 14:99:e2:04:52:5c;
  uid "\001\024\231\342\004R\\";
}
```

Which seems to work :-)

Comment: The `-0175` is really cool! However it doesn't print anything for me, when I try your version.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting: Hmm... I'm using a newer Perl (5.26.1) but I can't see anything in my code that would be affected by that.

Comment: Just tested with 5.26.2 and doesn't work there either. Could it be an encoding issue? `file` says it is just "ASCII text".

Answer (score 2):

In case You wanna AWK solution:

```
awk '/^lease/ { rem=0; } /^lease 192\.168\.234\.2/ { rem=1; } !rem' dhcpd.leases
```

Solution with passing BASH variable containing IP address to AWK:

```
awk '/^lease/ { rem=0; } /^lease '${var//./\\.}'/ { rem=1; } !rem' dhcpd.leases
```

As You see above in addition You have to escape each occurrence of dot (that's done by bash variable substitution `${var//./\\.}` ), similar You did in PERL, because is part of regexp.

Test:

```
$ var='192.168.234.2'
$ awk '/^lease/ { rem=0; } /^lease '${var//./\\.}'/ { rem=1; } !rem' dhcpd.leases
lease 192.168.234.5 {
  starts 3 2018/11/21 18:53:11;
  ends 3 2018/11/21 18:54:11;
  tstp 3 2018/11/21 18:54:11;
  cltt 3 2018/11/21 18:53:11;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 14:99:e2:04:52:5c;
  uid "\001\024\231\342\004R\\";
}
lease 192.168.234.13 {
  starts 3 2018/11/21 21:38:16;
  ends 3 2018/11/21 21:38:27;
  tstp 3 2018/11/21 21:38:27;
  cltt 3 2018/11/21 21:38:16;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:e0:6f:11:7f:59;
  uid "\001\000\340o\021\177Y";
}
```

Comment: I added solution with passing bash variable into answer.

Answer (score 2):

Problems:

- You are printing all or nothing. Instead, use `s///` to remove the unwanted parts, then print unconditionally (say by using `-p` instead of `-n`).
- `.` won't match line feeds. This is fixed by using `/s`.
- `-l` doesn't make sense with `-0777` (but it doesn't hurt either).

Fixed:

```
perl -0777spe's/^lease \Q$ip\E \{.*?^\}\n//sm' -- -ip=$ip dhcpd.leases
```

Additions changes:

- Added a couple of `/^/m` to limit where things can match to speed things up and to stop if from malfunctioning if `}` is found elsewhere.
- Removed the line feed that followed the `}`.
- Added `\Q\E` around `$ip` to ensure the value matches literally.

Answer (score 1):

`gawk` comes with multi character record delimiters:

```
gawk -v ip="${ip}" 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="}\n"} $0 !~ ip' dhcp.leases
```

We split the input file into records delimited by `}\n`. It is safe to do so because the input file is auto-generated by the dhcp server and guaranteed to be free of newlines and other garbage.

Having that, we can just print those records which do not match the ip.

---

PS: If you are willing to accept an additional empty newline, which doesn't hurt and only happens in case the first record gets deleted, you can use a portable POSIX `awk` command:

```
awk -v ip="${ip}" 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="}"} $0 !~ ip' dhcp.leases
```

Note: POSIX defines `RS` as a single char.

Answer (score 1):

Your data has a regular structure. In such cases I always use the `...` (range) operator:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $ip    = "192.168.234.13";
my $regex = qr,^lease \Q${ip}\E \{$,;
while (<DATA>) {
    if (/$regex/.../^\}/) {
    # inside lease
    print "MATCHED $_";
    } else {
    print "OTHER   $_";
    }
}

__DATA__
lease 192.168.234.5 {
  starts 3 2018/11/21 18:53:11;
  ends 3 2018/11/21 18:54:11;
  tstp 3 2018/11/21 18:54:11;
  cltt 3 2018/11/21 18:53:11;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 14:99:e2:04:52:5c;
  uid "\001\024\231\342\004R\\";
}
lease 192.168.234.13 {
  starts 3 2018/11/21 21:38:16;
  ends 3 2018/11/21 21:38:27;
  tstp 3 2018/11/21 21:38:27;
  cltt 3 2018/11/21 21:38:16;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:e0:6f:11:7f:59;
  uid "\001\000\340o\021\177Y";
}
```

Example output:

```
OTHER   lease 192.168.234.5 {
OTHER     starts 3 2018/11/21 18:53:11;
OTHER     ends 3 2018/11/21 18:54:11;
OTHER     tstp 3 2018/11/21 18:54:11;
OTHER     cltt 3 2018/11/21 18:53:11;
OTHER     binding state free;
OTHER     hardware ethernet 14:99:e2:04:52:5c;
OTHER     uid "\001\024\231\342\004R\\";
OTHER   }
MATCHED lease 192.168.234.13 {
MATCHED   starts 3 2018/11/21 21:38:16;
MATCHED   ends 3 2018/11/21 21:38:27;
MATCHED   tstp 3 2018/11/21 21:38:27;
MATCHED   cltt 3 2018/11/21 21:38:16;
MATCHED   binding state free;
MATCHED   hardware ethernet 00:e0:6f:11:7f:59;
MATCHED   uid "\001\000\340o\021\177Y";
MATCHED }
```

or as a one-liner:

```
perl -ne 'if (/^lease 192\.168\.234\.13 \{$/.../^\}/) { print }'
```